# proper use link hreflang

Tags: html, seo, multiple-languages

I use below link tag for multiple language,  have two question

1. should I add `<link href="http://domain.com/" rel="canonical">` in url `http://domain.com/?hl=en` or `http://domain.com/?hl=es`?
2. should I add `<html lang='en'>` in url `http://domain.com/?hl=en` and  `<html lang='es'>` in `http://domain.com/?hl=es`?

```
<head>
  <!-- … -->
  <link href="http://domain.com/" hreflang="x-default" rel="alternate">
  <link href="http://domain.com/?hl=en" hreflang="en" rel="alternate">
  <link href="http://domain.com/?hl=es" hreflang="es" rel="alternate">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. should I add < link href="http://domain.com/" rel="canonical" > in url
   http://domain.com/?hl=en or http://domain.com/?hl=es?

Neither, you can use:

```
<link href="http://domain.com/" rel="canonical"> in http://domain.com/
<link href="http://domain.com/?hl=en" rel="canonical"> in http://domain.com/?hl=en
<link href="http://domain.com/?hl=es" rel="canonical"> in http://domain.com/?hl=es
```

2. should I add < html lang='en' > in url http://domain.com/?hl=en or
   http://domain.com/?hl=es?

You can put it in http://domain.com/?hl=en, but not in http://domain.com/?hl=es

Comment: thanks for reply.  1 I found this https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq-internationalisation#q20 it seems told not to use `canonical` with `hreflang="en"`  I don't get it.  and if I add canonical  in multiple link tag like you do then canonical seems meanless ? what is canonical  actually do? 2 if I add `< html lang='en' >` in url http://domain.com/?hl=en  should I add  `< html lang='es' >` in url http://domain.com/?hl=es  too?  what is `<html lang = '..'>` actually do?

Comment: No, that is not what Google says in your link. In my answer, I say you 'can', not you 'should'. If some of your content can be accessed with different URLs, then canonical links help search engine merge both URLs. You can put lang='es' in your Spanish page. It tells search engines the content is in Spanish.

Comment: I have this question because II get error message in google webmaster tools `en - no return tags
es - no return tags` so I'm not sure what cause this error message ? according your answer it seems if I add `<link href="http://domain.com/" rel="canonical">` in both different language url nothing wrong?

Comment: Check this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/67059/10346 + I did not say you should put <link href="http://domain.com/" rel="canonical"> in both different language.

Comment: I googled to see this before , but I just don't get it what is link back mean? every answer and google document say that , but I can't find a example code....

Comment: If the english page says there is a spanish page, then the spanish page should say there is an English page too. Sometimes, this message is displayed when there is a redirect. The hreflang on the page is ignored.

Comment: does that mean I need to put `<link href="http://domain.com/?hl=en" hreflang="en" rel="alternate">
  <link href="http://domain.com/?hl=es" hreflang="es" rel="alternate">` in both url page?

Comment: Yes. See here for more details: https://seosummaries.com/expertise/internationalization-multi-language-seo-checklist.html

Comment: I did that already that's why I get confused  any possible because I set rel canonical or html lang attr

Comment: No it is not related to canonical or lang attribute. Maybe Google has not reprocessed your pages or has not updated info in GWT yet. If the issue persists, you should report it to Google's Webmaster Forum.